# Анимация загрузки при запросах

Tags: php, javascript, запрос

Как на JavaScript осуществить появление анимации при запросе (`file_get_contents()`), чтобы, когда данные получены, анимация исчезала и появлялся контент? И всё на одной странице.

Comment: как сделать так, чтобы когда я смываю в унитазе, на красной площади появлялся фонтан из горячего шоколада. У когда смыв закончен, появлялся бы Иван Грозный, на белом слоне ?

Comment: чисто теоретически это можно решить примерно так:
делаем long poll к серверу, выдаем спец строку - типа `echo "Event: Animation Begin\n`; делаем flush потом читаем контент в строку (file_get_content) выдаем "echo "Event: Animation End\n"; flush(). вываливаем строку браузеру. exit; 

ну и есть другие варианты. похожие, но файл выдавать сразу через readfile. с управляющими строками... вопрос н.. зачем вам это надо.

Comment: Может я не так объяснил. Я захожу на страницу у меня получаются данные через f_g_c И в это время появляется анимация загрузки. Затем когда данные получены анимация исчезает и появляется текст

Comment: file_get_contents() возвращает строку. строку он возвращает php. вам судя по вопросу хочется сказать браузеру (наш диск из середины 90х будет читать такой большой файл несколько секунд, так-что ждите). Если же это не так, то вам надо использовать readfile (сразу выводить файл) и ajax запрос, лучше используйте jquery, т.к. иначе вы еще месяц потратите на то чтобы делать это кроссбраузерно и понимать что к чему.

Comment: Ну вот у меня медленный интернет и меня как то не радует смотреть на белую страницу лучше при  file_get_contents и preg_match_all смотреть на загрузку

Comment: я боюсь вы не совсем точно изложили свой вопрос т.к. file_get_contents на сервере выполняется менее секунды.

Comment: Ну это да, а у меня preg_match_all  тормозит всё так как он присутствует   в коде 12 раз

Answer (score 2):

1. загружается "пустая" страница, скрипты, и анимированный гиф индикатора загрузки (крутится-вертится);
2. выполняется ajax запрос к php скрипту, который читает данные через `file_get_contents()` и передает их полчаса в браузер. Все это время продолжает крутиться индикатор загрузки "ждите ответа";
3. по окончании приема данных выполняется callback функция JS, получающая на вход принятые данные. Она скрывает индикатор загрузки и показывает принятый текст или html.

Удобнее-проще реализовать с помощью JS библиотеки, напр. jQuery. Много букв: [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Без лишних слов: [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

JS будет примерно таким:

```
$.get('http://site.ru/fgc.php', function(data) {
    $('.inProgress').hide(); // спрятали индикатор загрузки
    $('.result').html(data); // показали принятые данные
});
```